# what's the right example for `Projection of Tuple DataSet` in official document?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm learning Flink [DataSet Transformations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html) Now,

the part I'm reading is `Projection of Tuple DataSet`

but the example`senv.fromElements(1,6.56,"study")` for `in` is wrong,

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class dataset_api {

StreamExecutionEnvironment senv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataSet<Tuple3<Integer, Double, String>> in=senv.fromElements(1,6.56,"study");
// converts Tuple3<Integer, Double, String> into Tuple2<String, Integer>
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out = in.project(2,0);

}
```

what's the right example for above code?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the DataSet API with a `StreamExecutionEnvironment`.

```java
ExecutionEnvironment bEnv = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataSet<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Integer>> foo3 = bEnv.fromElements(new Tuple3<>(1, 2, 3));
DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> foo2 =  foo3.project(2, 0);
```